# Defining a procedure that plots a function with its derivative but yields no output

Tags: sage

I'm trying to define a procedure that plots a function on an interval (a,b) along with its first derivative

```
def graph(f,a,b):
g(x)=f
h(x)=g.diff(x,1)
g1=plot(g,a,b)
g2=plot(h,a,b)
(g1+g2).show
```

but when i try it, for example with

```
graph(x^2,1,2)
```

there is no output.
I'd appreciate any hints/help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so meanwhile I've figured it out

```
def graph(f,a,b):
g(x)=f
h(x)=g.diff(x,1)
g1=plot(g,a,b)
g2=plot(h,a,b)
p=(g1+g2)
return p
```

does the trick